# JAVA SFTP file transfer

Tags: java, file, jsch

Anyone please help me with file transfer in java using JSCH API. 
I am able to successfully do the file transfer using this API
but I want to know how to maintain keys in hosts file for validation with server.

Also please tell is it mandatory to use keys for `SFTP` or `SCP` file transfer or without public/private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your private keys in OpenSSH format in a file.  You identify that file in your program with Jsch.setKnownHosts.  See example at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/KnownHosts.java.html.  Using the keys is optional, but recommended for security vs. use of explicit passwords.